# Changing the Content-Type of error responses in the Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need **all** error responses in my API to adhere to the [Internet Draft "Problem Details for HTTP APIs"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-http-problem-00), which in the context of the Django Rest Framework could simply mean to change the Content-Type of JSON responses to "application/problem+json", while successful responses stick with "application/json". What's the best way to accomplish this?

I considered creating a custom exception handler that would do the following:

1. If "application/problem+json" is not accepted by the client, a "406 Not Acceptable" response is returned.
2. Otherwise, call *rest_framework.views:exception_handler()* and set the response's content type to "application/problem+json". (Assuming that I have a rendered for this type.)

Is there a better way to accomplish this? If not, can you spot any problems with this approach?